# Obtain the mean of X the number of red balls drawn

Tags: probability, means

> Urn 1 contains 2R balls and 1W, Urn 2 contains 2W balls and 1R. using a fair coin of head to choose Urn 1 and otherwise 2. Two balls are drawn randomly without replacement from the chosen Urn. X is the number of Red balls. we need the mean of X.

I started by Finding the probability of obtaining all the cases

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
n & \text{URN1} & \text{URN2} & \text{P(n|Urn1)+P(n|Urn2)}\\
\hline
2R & 1/2\times2/3\times1/2 & 1/2\times1/3\times0 & 1/6 \\
1R & 1/2\times2/3\times1/2 & 1/2\times1/3\times1 & 1/3\\
0R & 1/2\times1/3\times0 & 1/2\times2/3\times1/2 & 1/6
\end{array}
$$

the result by the book is 1 while by me after multiplying $xp(x)$ is $0.5$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1735006/probability-of-selecting-a-white-ball/1735199#1735199

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only took into account one of two orders of drawing one red and one white ball (for each urn).

Comment: why combination order does matter here ?

Comment: @Feras: A decision tree will illustrate that. (Also note that your probabilities don't add up to $1$.)

Comment: all possible ways. after considering the two orders it sums to 1. thanks

Answer (score 1):

See the answer of Joriki for what went wrong.

Actually this can be solved more directly on base of symmetry and linearity of expectation.

Let $Y$ denote the number of white balls drawn so that $X+Y=2$ and consequently $$\mathbb EX+\mathbb EY=\mathbb E(X+Y)=2$$

Then realize that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution so that $$\mathbb EX=\mathbb EY$$